# Columns names cut in half and data bad encoded with pyodbc and Teradata database

Tags: python, teradata, python-3.7, pyodbc, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to do a simple 'SELECT' query on my Teradata database but my columns names are cut in half.
And when I try to convert my data returned to a dictionnay I found out all informations are not right encoded. Informations come from the public star wars API : https://swapi.co/

Here a screenshot of my results in console :

[image]

Here my code :

```
from database import Utils
import pyodbc

connection_string = "driver={Teradata};dbcname=my_database;DefaultDatabase=something;uid=my_user;pwd=password;charset=utf8;"

oConnexion = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
import pandas as pd
query="SELECT * FROM DEV_EDW.STAR_WARS_CHARACTERS;"

oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8')
oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')


data=pd.read_sql(query, oConnexion)
print(data)

for col in data.columns: 
    print(col) 

dictionary = data.to_dict('records')
print(dictionary)
```

I have already tried :

- Connecting using another user
- Connecting using another database/table/datas
- Connecting using a cursor
- Using another encoding : oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-32') as said here : https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/194 :

[image]

Here part of results of pip freeze :

```
pandas==0.25.3
pyodbc==4.0.27
python-apt==1.6.4
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-debian==0.1.32
```

Any help appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. I do not need decoding lines.

```
#oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
#oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
#oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8')
#oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

Everything working well without :

[image]

Comment: The proper encoding / decoding and whether or not you need to explicitly override will depend on the combination of platform, ODBC driver manager, and Teradata ODBC driver version. You may want to consider using *teradatasql* instead of *pyodbc* + ODBC driver

Comment: I just arrived on the project, good to know there is python package just to manage connection to Teradata.
I was following an internal tutorial wich has been created one year ago but it's already depreciated.